# What are some profanity words in classical Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary, classical-chinese

It is easy to find profanity words for modern Chinese, but I could not find any profanity words for classical Chinese. Even such simple ones as "to fuck". Please help to promote this knowledge.

Comment: There are many bilingual versions of classical Chinese texts on line.  You should go through them and look for the words you want.

Comment: yes, but than, how many million words i have to go through until i scream "bingo! there is fuck"

Comment: So you see my point.

Comment: If it is hard for me to collect all the profanity of classical chinese into one list, it does not mean there are or have been some brilliant ethusiasts who have not done it already. made but undiscovered by the masses.

Comment: You will not find any, for the simple reason that it would not be appropriate expressing lewdness in the intellectual setting of classical Chinese, and if it was done anyway as a prank, it would most likely not survive.

Most such language has been expressed using vernacular language (as in 金瓶梅 or in the poems of 李白). Similar wording in classical Chinese would be written euphemistically, using analogies and references to "jade" this and that.

Comment: Will "clouds and rain" do it for you?  That's  云雨 and may possibly have a classical origin.

Comment: you do not know by chance a sentence in classical chinese using this expression? can it be used as a verb in classical chinese?

Comment: Are you looking for sex-related words like coitus in classical Chinese, or profanity/taboo words (some of which are not about sex at all), or swearing words?

Comment: all kinds of, not just sex.

Answer (score 3):

As to classical Chinese in the strict sense I know no examples.  Going up to 8th century, The poem "To send far way" by Li Bai (701--762), also known as Li Po, contains two lines translated by David Hinton as

We made clouds and rain love our farewell,
Then nothing but autumn grasses remained.

I cannot find the Chinese on line.  The expression is often traced back further to a classical work "Gao Tang Fu/高唐賦" (for which my historical source is https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_Yu) and you can see the original at https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/高唐賦.  But that work only sets up a vague association between sex, clouds and rain.  The phrase  "clouds and rain/云雨" for sex seems to owe more to Du Fu's Tang Dynasty poem: " Wu Gorge and more clouds and rain the night," see http://baike.baidu.com/view/130025.htm

For whatever reason, the phrase "clouds and rain/云雨" has come to refer to sex.  It is not a verb.

For more, follow the advice of 倪阔乐 above.  I am afraid you will not find what you are looking for.

Comment: yeah, it seems i should have asked for euphemisms or metaphors.